# Defining control variables and objective function in GEKKO

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, modeling, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I've the following dynamical system that I am trying to solve in GEKKO

> (1)
>             
>             
>               
>                 
>                   d
>                   ϕ
>                 
>                 
>                   d
>                   t
>                 
>               
>               =
>               −
>               
>                 M
>                 T
>               
>               D
>               M
>               ϕ

I followed examples given [here](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/PartialDifferentialEquations) to set up the following equations in GEKKO

```
M, MT = get_mmt()
A = MT @ np.diag(Dhat) @ M
A = A[1:ngrid - 1]

# first node
m.Equation(phi_hat[0].dt() == 0)

# interior nodes
int_value = -A @ phi_hat  # function value at interior nodes
m.Equations(phi_hat[i].dt() == int_value[i] for i in range(0, ngrid-2))

# terminal node
m.Equation(phi_hat[ngrid-1].dt() == Dhat[end] * 2 * (phi_hat[end-1] - phi_hat[end]))
```

The state variables are phi_hat. I want to minimize the squared error difference between phi_meas and phi_hat from the model. Therefore, the following setting are used.

```
phi_hat = [m.Var(value=phi_0[i]) for i in range(ngrid)]
phi_hat = m.CV(value=phi_meas)
phi_hat.FSTATUS = 1  # fit to measurement phi obtained from 'def actual'
```

The error has to be minimized by optimizing parameter D (same as Dhat below) in equation 1.

```
Dhat0 = 500*np.ones(ngrid-1)
Dhat = m.FV(value=Dhat0[i] for i in range(0, ngrid-1))
Dhat.STATUS = 1  # adjustable parameter
```

I hope these settings are right. Please correct me if these are wrong. I am a little confused here, not sure if I should be using `Dhat = m.CV(value=Dhat0[i] for i in range(0, ngrid-1))` in place of `m.FV`. `Dhat` is a vector of control variables that have to be estimated.

Post this, I'd like to ask for help on how to define the objective function `(f = sum((phi(:) - phi_tilde(:)).^2))` using m.Minimize().

I have got the following settings for simulation

```
m.options.IMODE = 5  # simultaneous dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 5  # collocation nodes
m.solve()
```

EDIT: Detailed description of the problem that I am trying to solve can be found [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34763/setting-up-optimization-problem-in-gekko). Note: Equation 1 mentioned here is actually equation 2 [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34763/setting-up-optimization-problem-in-gekko).

Comment: Similar question on SciComp: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34763/setting-up-optimization-problem-in-gekko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question about using `FV` or `CV`:

- `FV` if it is a parameter value that can either be set to a fixed value or else adjusted by an optimizer to minimize an objective
- `CV` if it is a variable that is determined by solving equations. The `CV` is different than a regular `Var` or `SV` in that there are [extra equations added to facilitate matching to available measurements](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorObjective).

From your description, it sounds like it should be an `FV`. As a first step in solving your problem, I recommend that you verify that you have the specifications correctly set by switching to `m.options.IMODE=7` and solve. This will tell you if you have the same number of equations and variables and also [initializes the model](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ModelInitialization) so that parameter estimation is faster.

If you use a `CV` then the squared error objective function is defined for you with `m.options.EV_TYPE=2`. You can also use `m.Minimize()` if you define the `CV` as a `Var` instead.